# leftover EFI files in hidden partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mac

So I have tried to install Linux (unsuccessfully) multiple times and when I run `diskutil list`, I get this:

[image]

`disk1` is my usb and `disk0` is my hard drive (which is flash storage if that makes a difference) and I am running OSX 10.9.2. 
When I go to Disk Utilities it doesn't show the EFI partition and I have tried completely erasing my USB but this EFI partition is still there. 
Will this interfere with if I try to install Linux again and how do I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

OS X's Disk Utility hides the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) from the user. If you want to modify it, you must use other tools, such as `diskutil` or [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/). You can explicitly mount the partition from the command line in OS X. The commands are:

```
mkdir /Volumes/ESP
sudo mount_msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP
```

You can then modify the contents of the ESP. Ubuntu's files will be in a directory called `EFI/ubuntu`.

This shouldn't be necessary, though, particularly not if you intend to re-install Ubuntu again. The new installation will simply overwrite the files from the old one.